# Using iPhone Gyrometer in a Moving Car

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, accelerometer, gyroscope

I've been trying to determine how the iPhone Gyrometer can be used for a driver safety app and I Have been very confused about it.  I know that the Gyrometer in the phone can measure changes and rotations of the phone itself, but can it be used to measure changes that take place while the phone is in a moving car?

For example, would it still be able to provide the rotation rates if it's not the phone being moved but rather the phone is stationary in a moving car?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gyroscope is a physical device (albeit at a minuscule level) that observes the same physical law as a toy gyroscope does by spinning — conservation of momentum.

It'll therefore recognise any changes within its inertial frame.

So, subject to precision, it'll recognise any turning that you, as a human being, recognise. It'll spot the rotational part of any force that you can feel.

For example, if the car you're in is driving smoothly in a straight line, it should pick up very little. If the car brakes abruptly such that the rear elevates relative to the front, it'll pick that up. If you performed [doughnuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doughnut_(driving)) (safety tip: don't), it should continuously spot orientation changes for the entire period.